# Hierarchical c# sorting recursively

Tags: c#, sorting, recursion

I have a data structure typed like this:

```
 class Something {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Something> Children {get; set;}

   public Something() {
     Children = new List<Something>();
   }
 }
```

Example Data:

```
    var one = new Something();
    one.Name = "B";

    var two = new Something();
    two.Name = "A";

    var three = new Something();
    three.Name = "C";

    one.Children.Add(new Something { Name = "F"});
    one.Children.Add(new Something { Name = "E"});
    one.Children.Add(new Something { Name = "D"});

    three.Children.Add(new Something { Name = "F"});
    three.Children.Add(new Something { Name = "E"});
    three.Children.Add(new Something { Name = "D"});

    var data = new List<Something>();
    data.Add(one);
    data.Add(two);
    data.Add(three);
```

I need a function to sort the field at *all levels*.  The *depth* of the tree is *arbitrary*.

I have this so far:

```
public static List<Something> SortTree(List<Something> node) {
  if (node == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return node
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(y => {
       if (y.Children.Count() > 0) {
         var t = y.Children;
         SortTree(t.ToList());
       }

       return y;
    })
    .ToList();
  }
```

Calling `SortTree(data)` returns the data with only the parent level sorted.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As a note the `.ToList()` in `SortTree(t.ToList());` doesn't seem to be needed since `y.Children` is already a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line

```
SortTree(t.ToList());
```

you are directly discarding the result since you're never actually updating the `Children` field.

You probably want something like

```
y.Children = SortTree(y.Children.ToList());
```

Although I would try to change your `SortTree()` to a method that does not return a value.

Comment: I've accepted this as an answer as it was the missing part I was looking for.  However I would recommend looking at Dmitry's answer if you don't want to run into any issues that he outlines in his comment.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a *mesh* (not just a *tree*) with loops (child is parent of itself) you'll be in trouble with *recoursion*. Another possible issue (the same *stack overflow*) is when the graph is *too deep* ("The depth of the tree is *arbitrary*"). I suggest a bit modified *BFS*
algorithm

```
public static List<Something> SortTree(List<Something> node) {
  Queue<List<Something>> agenda = new Queue<List<Something>>();

  agenda.Enqueue(node);

  HashSet<List<Something>> alreadySorted = new HashSet<List<Something>>() { null };

  while (agenda.Any()) {
    var current = agenda.Dequeue();

    if (alreadySorted.Add(current)) {
      current.Sort((left, right) => string.Compare(left.Name, right.Name));

      foreach (var child in current)
        agenda.Enqueue(child.Children);
    }
  }

  return node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry this works as well.  Do you have any good documentation you recommend on Queues and Stacks?

Comment: @codeAline: I think standard MSDN manual is the best to start from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2c

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do recursive anything, you do not get around writing your own loop. At least to my knowledge (wich is far from complete), you can not continue to just use linq. You have to write the sorting loop yourself.

At wich point recursively calling "SortTree(current);" becomes trivial

Comment: Do you mean using foreach instead of select?  Do you mind posting an example please.